# Osmdroid block buttons - android studio

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm struggling with this problem : I created a new activity with a map to get a geographic position. To confirm the position I'm using a button but it doesn't work. We can click on it but it doesn't do anything. I finally understood that the map was blocking it and I don't know why.

Here's the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_exit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:text="@string/save_position" />

<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="429dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity

```
public class PickLocation extends AppCompatActivity {

private MapView map;
private final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
MyLocationNewOverlay mLocationOverlay;
IMapController mapController;
Context context;
Marker marker;
private Button exitButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_location);
    context = getApplicationContext();

    this.exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_exit);
    this.exitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("result", marker.getPosition().toString());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            PickLocation.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    Configuration.getInstance().load(context,
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context));


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_location);
    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);

    mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(context),map);
    mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    map.getOverlays().add(this.mLocationOverlay);

    mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(8.);
    mapController.setCenter(mLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());

    marker = new Marker(map, context);
    marker.setDefaultIcon();

    MapEventsReceiver mapEventsReceiver = new MapEventsReceiver() {
        @Override
        public boolean singleTapConfirmedHelper(GeoPoint p) {
            marker.setPosition(p);
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean longPressHelper(GeoPoint p) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    MapEventsOverlay eventsOverlay = new MapEventsOverlay(mapEventsReceiver);
    map.getOverlays().add(marker);
    map.getOverlays().add(eventsOverlay);

    requestPermissionsIfNecessary(
        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}
    );
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    map.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    map.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
        permissionsToRequest.add(permissions[i]);
    }
    if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[0]),
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

private void requestPermissionsIfNecessary(String[] permissions) {
    ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsToRequest.add(permission);
        }
    }
    if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[0]),
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
}
```

I tried to replace the content of the onClick by a simple toast and it still doesn't work. I don't see what's wrong in this. Thank you for your consideration

Comment: I don't see any reference to a toast message in your code.